# How to add the footer with social icons in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my footer image with social icons. I need to know how to add that using bootstrap/css??

As like the picture shown. I need to know how to add that using bootstrap or css? How to design that separation? This is my code for the footer.

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container text-left">
            <small style="color:grey" class="copyright">Copyright &copy 2015 SVAPP Private Limited.All Rights Reserved.</small>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-skype pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook pull-right">  </small></a>
        </div><!--End container-->
    </footer><!--End footer 2-->
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVKWF.jpg)

Comment: from which web site you make the screen ?

http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

Comment: it is photoshop design... I need to design that in web

Comment: did you include bootstrap.css and bootstrap-social.css ?
<script type='text/javascript' src="...... /bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: re updated my answer, did the code work for you ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one solution how you can create this using **Bootstrap** and [**Font awesome**](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) icons. Bootstrap [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) don't have social icons so you can include some other icons font.

```css
.footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You can also create this without Bootstrap framework and css will be almost the same, you just need to include icons font.

```css
footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

look in http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/ where you can get the icons for boostrap.

UPDATE 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.10.1/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <body>
       <div class="text-center">
        <a onclick="" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a onclick="" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-dropbox"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i></a>
        <a onclick="" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-flickr"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
        <a onclick="" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```